# ios 8.3 NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute crash

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios8.3

I got a strange problem with my NSLayoutConstraint.

I have recently updated my iPhone to 8.3 and using latest Xcode.

The app is crashing on iOS 8.3 and the breakpoint is pointing me to:

```
self.triangleTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.triangle
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:nil
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0];

[self addConstraint:self.triangleTopConstraint];
```

That was working prior to iOS 8.3.

However, I read on this page here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSLayoutAttribute

It says to use `NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute` when the relationship has no second view. So I changed it to this:

```
self.triangleTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.triangle
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:nil
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0];

[self addConstraint:self.triangleTopConstraint];
```

But the app is still crashing on iOS 8.3.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: It "was working" how? You could never set the _top_ of something to an absolute value. I don't know what your code was doing but it was always wrong.

Comment: I have a subview called triangle which is subview of a custom view. I am using this animation constraint to change the Y coordinate of the triangle subview. How would I go about achieving what I want using the proper way, please enlighten me matt

Comment: You set the top of `self.triangle` _in relation to_ something else, such as the top of its superview (it doesn't _have_ to be the top of the superview, that's just a particularly common thing to do so I'm using it as an example).

Comment: Also, please, when asking about a crash, show the console message generated by the crash. It is often full of important information!

Comment: Ah...sugar. I think I remember now. I'm getting confused with assigning a height value for a NSLayoutConstraint that isn't equal relative to another view and so I would use `nil`. Thanks for waking me up matt. If you post your comment as answer, I'll mark as accepted. There was no console output, Xcode would just keep stopping at the int main() {} recursively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set an absolute height or width value, and in that case you would use a `toItem` of `nil` and a second `attribute` of `NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute`; but you *cannot* set an absolute top. You must set the top *in relation to* something else — for example, in relation to the top of the superview (it doesn't *have* to be the top of the superview, that's just a particularly common thing to do so I'm using it as an example).

Comment: Only width or height can be constant and does not relate to any item.

Comment: By the way, it's not allowed to set multiplier to be zero, except that firstItem is width or height. Or else it will raise an exception as @Zhang said.